# CreateIndex of elasticsearch Nest client is not creating index after changing the version from 2.3.3 to 5.4

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an application working in Elasticsearch 2.3.3 with mapper-attachments. Now I upgraded to elasticsearch5.4. I used Nest client to Create index and Index Data.
Now indexing is not working.

My code to index is

```
var filters = new List<string> { "lowercase", "snowball", "nGram" }; 
        client.CreateIndex("mydocs", c => c
             .Settings(st => st
                       .Analysis(anl => anl
                       .Analyzers(h => h
                           .Custom("full", ff => ff
                                .Filters(filters)
                                .Tokenizer("standard"))
                           )
                           .TokenFilters(ba => ba
                               .Snowball("snowball", sn => sn
                                   .Language(SnowballLanguage.English)))
                           .TokenFilters(bases => bases
                           .EdgeNGram("nGram", gram => gram
                           .MaxGram(20)
                           .MinGram(3)
                           .Side(EdgeNGramSide.Front)
                           ))
                           )
                           .Setting("index.query.default_field", "file.content")
                           )

                        .Mappings(mp => mp
                        .Map<IndexDocument>(ms => ms
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Nested<ES.SearchEngine.Models.Attachment>(n => n
                                .Name(sc => sc.File)
                            .AutoMap()
                            ))
                       .Properties(at => at
                       .Attachment(a => a.Name(o => o.File)
                       .FileField(fl => fl.Analyzer("full").TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets).Store())
                       .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Title)
                       .Analyzer("full")
                       .TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)
                       )))                           
                       ))
                       );
```

Error

```
  {Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "Failed to parse mapping [indexdocument]: No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]" CausedBy: "Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [file]""}
```

Can anyone pls help.

Comment: Check below for more information. May be mapping is deprecated for attachments in ES 5.4. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-attachments.html

Comment: My issue resolved. I forgot to refresh the elasticsearch service after installing mapper-attachment plugin.